# Token generation run every 5 min once

Tags: jmeter

My token generator request will give "ext_expires_in":"599","expires_on":"1620730631". But i want to create token every 5 min once and i want to run another request()it is present in second parallel controller if token generator request is passed, the third parallel controller will use token as variable from 1st parallel controller and from second parallel controller also it will use some variables. In other thread I have so many requests. Those need to run continuously without waiting. Here each thread is independent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see any sense in using these [Parallel Controllers](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) because you have only one Sampler inside the parallel controller and the Parallel Controllers execute their children in parallel, just delete them, they don't add any value
2. The easiest way of running Token Generation request once per 5 minutes is moving it into a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). You can pass the token from that Thread Group to "main" thread group via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating from your Beanshell test elements

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok i will delete that parallel controller. But i have 3 token generators here in each thread